# How to show ellipsis for long cell values in kendo ui grid?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to show ellipsis for long values in kendo grid.
As per telerik forum, I need to set the folling in css

```
.k-grid td
{
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I am trying to set the styles in databound event of the grid like below

```
var grid = $("#kendoGrid").kendoGrid({
        columns: columnConfiguration,
        dataBound: function (e) {
$("#kendoGrid td").css("overflow", "hidden");                               
$("#kendoGrid td").css("text-overflow", "ellipsis");
},......other events and functions
```

But this is not working.The grid is still not showing the ellipsis.

How do i have to do to show the ellipsis. 
Note: I can't put this in a css file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add to the CSS `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.k-grid td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See it in action here : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/8U6rg/4/)

Comment: Is there any way i can display a tooltip for the ellipsis content?

Comment: Is this code IE 11 specific? The style is not working on IE 10.

Comment: Just tested my Fiddle  in IE10.0.9200.16921 and worked fine. No, it should not be specific of IE11 since this is old CSS (CSS1)

Comment: In a inline editing grid i also had to add .k-grid table { table-layout: fixed; }

Comment: @OnaBai Refering to your jsfiddle example: is there a way to achieve the same dynamically, ie. for each column or simply when a grid is built dynamically and you don't always know the column name?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Kendo, but a quick test (with firebug) on their demo seems to
show that setting:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis
white-space: nowrap
```

as CSS properties should do the trick.

Comment: which demo? can you give me the link?

Comment: I am setting the same properties, but trying to do it in databiund event as I cant set it in css.

Comment: For the tooltip, you could try setting a 'title' attribute on the <td>. Most browser will render it as a tooltip

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a css Class and then bind it in the dataBound property of KendoGrid

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1423/)

Code Snippet:

```
    dataBound:function() {
        $('td').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('ellipsisClass')
        })
    }
```

CSS Class:

```
.ellipsisClass {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I had to add white-space: nowrap to make it work.  Thanks for ur help though.

Comment: @syd: thought you want it in the function rather than applying it in the cssClass. Happy to help though

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with showing ellipsis in Kendo grid and I've tried all answers above without success. Solution in my case was very simple: this css class (text-overflow: ellipsis) was overwritten with another css setting in the code!
This class is set from Kendo as Default! So ellipsis should be available out of the box!
So if someone runs into same Problems just check following first:

1. Is `Scrollable()` grid property activated?
2. Is there any css `Settings` that prevent showing it?

Hope this additional answer will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution did not seem to work for me. The text was not hidden, resulting in large rows.
I tried the following :

```
.k-grid td
{
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

With this the text was displayed in one line and showed the ellipsis.